# $I$ finitely generated ideal with $I=I^2$, then $I$ is a direct summand of $R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring, and let $I$ be a finitely generated ideal in $R$ with $I=I^2$. 
>   Show that $I$ is a direct summand of $R$.

I managed to understand that $(1-z)I=0$ for some $z \in I$ with the property $z=z^2$. The solution says that it yields that $I$ is a direct summand.

How to show the following statement?

> Let $R$ be a ring, $I$ be an ideal of $R$ and $e$ be an impotent element of $I$. Then $R=eI\oplus J$ for some $J$

Help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $e$ is an idempotent then so is $1-e$ and $e(1-e)=0$. This means that $(e)\cap(1-e)=0$. Now notice that for all $r\in R$, $r=re+r(1-e)$ so $R=(e)\oplus (1-e)$. But $(e)\subset I$ and $I\cap (1-e)=0$ so $(e)=I$.

Comment: Why $I\cap (1-e)$ is $(0)$? Like I was thinking $I$ contain those elements e.g., $e$ for which $e^2=e$, then why not $1-e$ contain in $I$ as $(1-e)^2=1-e$? does finitely generated ideal condition limited $I$ to such idempotent! @user52045