# If $R$ is commutative and $I$ is a finitely generated ideal with $I^2=I$, then there exists an idempotent $e\in I$ with $I=Re$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, idempotents

**Question**

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. Let $I$ be a finitely generated ideal. Assume that $I^2=I$. Show that $I$ is a direct summand of $R$.

**Answer**

I know that $I=Re$ for some idempotent $e\in I$ and afterwards we can decompose $R=Re\oplus R(1-e)$. However, I couldn't prove why such an idempotent $e$ must exist in $I$. Any help/hint would be appreciated. Thanks in advance...

Related to these [two](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/601187/i-finitely-generated-ideal-with-i-i2-then-i-is-a-direct-summand-of-r) [questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3271108/prove-that-if-i-is-a-right-ideal-of-r-and-i-is-a-direct-summand-of-r-the).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a straightforward consequence of [Nakayama's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nakayama%27s_lemma#Statement) with $M=I$.

Once you have $r-1=i$ and $rI=\{0\}$, you have $r^2-r=ri=0$ so that $r^2=r$.

However, you are more interested in $e=1-r\in I$ which is then also an idempotent in $I$. We are going to be done if $eR=I$.

Fortunately, it is: since $1=e+(1-e)$ we can multiply by any $i\in I$ to get $i=ei+(1-e)i=ei+ri=ei$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't know such a lemma.